# Probability of attending cinema and theater.

Tags: probability

Problem: 
It is researched that 60% of people in city goes to cinema on daily basis, 40% of people goes to theater on daily basis. It is also known that 20% simultaneously goes to both theater and cinema.

What is

1. Probability that chosen person does not attend both.
2. Probability that chosen person attends theater OR cinema.
3. Probability that person, which attends cinema will
   attend theater too.
4. Probability that person, which attends theater will
   attend cinema too.
5. Probability that person, which doesn't attend theater
   will attend cinema.
6. Probability that person, which doesn't attend cinema
   will attend theater.

So far I have got:

1. **A**-person attends cinema
2. **B**-person attends theater

1)$P(\overline{A}\cap\overline{B})=P(\overline{A})\cdot P(\overline{B})=0.4\cdot 0.6=0.24$

2)$P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap A)=0.6+0.4-0.24=0.76$

I have no clear understanding of how to solve rest of questions.

For example,  in 3rd questions I guess that I need to find $P(A \cap B)$, which gives exactly the same as 4th questions $P(B \cap A)$, which seems unlikely for me.

And I guess that 5th and 6th would be:

5) $P(\overline{B}\cap A)=P(\overline{B})\cdot P(A)=0.6\cdot
   0.6=0.36$

6) $P(\overline{A}\cap B)=P(\overline{A})\cdot P(B)=0.4\cdot 0.4=0.16$

Is there a something I am not getting here?

Comment: Are you familiar with conditional probability?

Comment: So, for example, 3rd would be $P(B|A)$? Is that the way I should have considered it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a note to your solution of item (2), it should be $P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$. Regarding item (3)-(4), you are in fact not looking for the joint probability, but the conditional probability i.e. $P(B|A)$ and $P(A|B)$ respectively, where the conditional probability is defined as usual:
\begin{equation}
P(X|Y) = \frac{P(X\cap Y)}{P(Y)}.
\end{equation}
The solutions to items (5)-(6) are found using the conditional probability as well. That is, by $P(A|\bar{B})$ and $P(B|\bar{A})$ respectively.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

For question **3**: You are looking for a probability that person attends theater **from those** that attend cinema. Therefore;

$$
P(person \space attends \space theater \space | \space person \space attends \space cinema)=P(B|A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}=\frac{0.24}{0.6}=\frac{2}{5}
$$

You can easily continue from there for other questions.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a venn diagram first. Makes life a lot easier.

Q 3 to 6 are of conditional probability.. Remember the basic formulae for conditional probability

P(A|B) = P(A ∩ B) / P(B)

Even better solve everything with the help of venn diagram

Say, if you've to calculate P(A given B) then

first check what region is covered by B. Now B is your new sample space. What is the total probability of this region?

This probability goes in the denominator.

Then inside B, how much area is taken by A? This goes in the numerator.

This will give you P(A|B)

Comment: That is a very interesting point of view, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

On your answer (1), you are implying that the two events are independent which does not seem to be the case.
I would have use the De Morgan's Law to solve it:

$$ \Pr \big( ( A \cup B ) ^ { \mathrm c } \big) = 1 - \Pr ( A \cup B ) = 0.2 $$

$$ \Pr \big( ( A \cup B ) ^ { \mathrm c } \big) = \Pr ( A ^ { \mathrm c } \cap B ^ { \mathrm c } ) $$